# I am looking to create a regular expression the can match either VALID TIL|UNTIL ddhhmm OR VALID ddhhmm/ddhhmm

Tags: regex-group

Cannot get REGEX pattern matching working.

This regex pattern `^VALID(?: (?:TIL|UNTIL) \d{6}| \d{6}[-\/]\d{6})` matches

```
VALID 222200/222300
VALID 222200-222300
VALID TIL 222200
VALID UNTIL 222200
```

But it also matches (these times are not valid for ddhhmm):

```
VALID 123456/789012
VALID 123456-789012
VALID TIL 123456
VALID UNTIL 123456
```

I tried correcting to the following but it is not working:

```
^VALID(?: (?:TIL|UNTIL) ([012]\d|[3][01])([01][0-9]|[2][0-3])([0-5]\d{1})[-\/]([012]\d|[3][01])([01][0-9]|[2][0-3])([0-5]\d{1}))
```

Look for:
VALID at the beginning of the line followed by optional TIL or UNTIL
dd 0,1,2 followed by any digit OR a 3 followed by a 0 or 1
hh 0 or 1 followed by 0 through 9 OR a 2 followed by 0 through 3
mm 0 through 5 followed by any digit
“-|/” a hyphen or slash
dd 0,1,2 followed by any digit OR a 3 followed by a 0 or 1
hh 0 or 1 followed by 0 through 9 OR a 2 followed by 0 through 3
mm 0 through 5 followed by any digit

The above regex results in the values of ddhhmm being returned correctly, but there should only be 1 time required when TIL or UNTIL are present.

```
VALID TIL 222200-222300 
VALID UNTIL 222200/222300
```

But does not match

VALID 222200-222300  No TIL or UNTIL present will have two times ddhhmm/ddhhmm or ddhhmm-ddhhmm

Can this can be done in a single regular expression (if TIL or UNTIL is present resolve only 1 time, if NOT present, resolve 2 times with either a hyphen or slash between them)

Answer (score 1):

You could write the alternation, and if you want to keep all the capture groups like:

```
^VALID (?:([012]\d|3[01])([01][0-9]|[2][0-3])([0-5]\d)[\/-]([012]\d|3[01])([01][0-9]|[2][0-3])([0-5]\d)|(?:UN)?TIL ([012]\d|3[01])([01][0-9]|[2][0-3])([0-5]\d))$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `VALID`  Match literally
- `(?:` Non capture group for the 2 alternatives

  - `([012]\d|3[01])([01][0-9]|[2][0-3])([0-5]\d)[\/-]([012]\d|3[01])([01][0-9]|[2][0-3])([0-5]\d)` Match 2 times the number pattern with either `-` or `/` in between
  - `|` Or
  - `(?:UN)?TIL ([012]\d|3[01])([01][0-9]|[2][0-3])([0-5]\d)` Match UNTIL or TIL followed by the number pattern
- `)` Close non capture group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lw6bnc/1)

Comment: Thank you for the response, as it turns out, we are using POSIX regex and POSIX regex doesn't allow non-grouping "(?...)"

Comment: @ReidCarnes Then you can use a capture group `()` and for posix see which characters to escape https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions